# How to properly setup python on Visual Studio Code? My debugging is not working right

Tags: python, python-3.x

On the newest version of python and I'm running it through visual studio code.

Anyways I set the python path in user settings and then wrote print ("hello") went to debug tab and pressed the green play button. But my code doesn't get highlighted and nothing pops up on my screen.

Here is a screenshot of my current window: [image: My debugging screen]

my user settings [image]

I was watching this video and trying to set it up but mine doesn't give me any options like the video. [image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your debug session hasn't been configured yet because the screenshot shows *DEBUG > No Configurations*. Click on the cog to the right to make up for it.